# How to allow WebAuthn work in React App iFrame in cross origin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, iframe, webauthn

I am trying to use WebAuthn which is integrated in my React App & use it as an iFrame in another website.

I am getting below Error :

> The following credential operations can only occur in a document which
> is same-origin with all of its ancestors: storage/retrieval of
> 'PasswordCredential' and 'FederatedCredential', storage of
> 'PublicKeyCredential'...

The website is in another domain & my react App iFrame domain is something else, so it gives this cross origin issue.

I have even tried below, but still the error occurs,

```
<iframe src="..." allow="publickey-credentials-get *" />
```

Anyone has another solution which will enable me to use WebAuthn in cross origin ?

Comment: Your `allow` attribute should work, and I've just checked that it works in Chrome. Are you doing a `navigator.credentials.create()` or `.get()` operation in the iframe? Only the latter is allowed.

Comment: @agl Yes, I am using both navigator.credentials.create() & navigator.credentials.get() in my iFrame.
Any solution for that to allow in cross origin ?

Comment: It is not currently possible to use `create` in an iframe. It [probably will become so](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1656#issuecomment-1219682589) in the future in order to enable some payments flows, but I don't have any timeline I'm afraid.

Comment: @agl Oh Noted with Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @agl mentioned in comment [section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671689/how-to-allow-webauthn-work-in-react-app-iframe-in-cross-origin#:%7E:text=It%20is%20not%20currently%20possible%20to%20use%20create%20in%20an%20iframe.), you can use  `navigator.credentials.get()` in ***Cross-origin*** if you explicitly allow it in Iframe ( like you did in your case ). But currently there is no support for using `navigator.credentials.create()` in ***Cross-origin*** ( there is already a open issue about it in [Github](https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1656) )